Why does Pycharm produce so many running instances on a remote linux server?
I'm using Pycharm with a mix of remote interpreter and Jupyter notebooks connecting to a Linux server. Pycharm produces too many 'instances' on the server, as follows. My question is why Pycharm produces so many 'instances' and never killed them. How to prevent this from happending? Or killed automatically if my processes ended?

